# Random Number Generation of Combination of six numbers

Tags: c, file, random, combinations

I am doing a Pseudo Random Number Generator that creates 100 combinations of 6 numbers from the range 1 to 56 with no repetition and then it saves them on a text file. Like this:

```
33 28 46 7 30 57 
15 29 43 41 16 21 
11 43 7 18 31 25 
36 32 19 42 47 33 
46 13 14 1 28 25 
33 14 55 43 29 13 
30 14 12 45 46 32 
56 31 54 32 20 21 
10 52 40 57 31 14 
28 44 15 47 57 45 
...
```

This is my code, but I feel that it is a little bit too big, specially the part when is checking no repetitions of the numbers

```
// Including C Standard Libraries
#include <stdint.h>  
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    // Initialing Random Generation C Library
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    // Variables for PRNG Loop
    uint16_t i;  
    uint8_t j; 

    uint8_t x[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    // Opening File to save Results
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("combinations.txt", "w+"); 

    // PRNF Loop
    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)  // Numbers of Combinations 
    {
        for(j = 0; j<6; j++)  // Number of Elements of the Combinations
        {
            x[j] = rand() % 57 + 1;  // Generating Random Number

            // Avoiding Repetition of Numbers
            if ( j==1)
            {
                while(x[1] == x[0])
                {
                    x[1] = rand() % 57 + 1;
                }
            }
            if ( j==2)
            {
                while(x[2] == x[0] || x[2] == x[1])
                {
                    x[2] = rand() % 57 + 1;
                }
            }
            if ( j==3)
            {
                while(x[3] == x[0] || x[3] == x[1] || x[3] == x[2] )
                {
                    x[3] = rand() % 57 + 1;
                }
            }
            if ( j==4)
            {
                while(x[4] == x[0] || x[4] == x[1] || x[4] == x[2] || x[4] == x[3] )
                {
                    x[4] = rand() % 57 + 1;
                }
            }
            if ( j==5)
            {
                while(x[5] == x[0] || x[5] == x[1] || x[5] == x[2] || x[5] == x[3] || x[5] == x[4] )
                {
                    x[5] = rand() % 57 + 1;
                }
            }


            fprintf(fp, "%d", x[j]);  // Saving Random Number in File
            fprintf(fp, " "); 
        } 

        fprintf(fp, "\n");  // Saving Newline  

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        {
            x[i] = 0;
        }    

    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the code?

Comment: instead of generation and checking for duplicate, you can shuffle array, look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array-using-fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm/

Comment: `rand() % 57 + 1` generates a random number from 1 to 57. Note that 1 and 57 both appear in your sample output.

Comment: 57 also appears? I want 1 to appear but 57 not .. so it must be 56 + 1 ?

Comment: The question is rather too open I suggest.  Perhaps "reduce the length of" or "simplify" rather the "improve".  The code can certainly be improved - in ways that don't concern you at the moment and will just be noise and opinion amongst what you really want to achieve.

Comment: It is rather odd to use `uint16_t` and such for loop variables, just use `int` (ok) or `size_t` (best)

Comment: Why it might never terminate? .. The code Is working .. I have already edited Clifford

Comment: what do you mean by a unique number? That is why I am checking for duplicates ..

Comment: Let's pretend that your local system, when generating your numbers from 1 - 57 cannot generate a "56".  Your program then would not terminate.  Nothing says that random will create a distribution of all numbers in your sequence, hence the comment.  From performance though, the shuffle idea is better.

Comment: Why the Local System might not be able of generate "56"? .. Even if it is not generated, I don't see what is the problem, there isn't any special condition for 56 or any other number ..  I am going to check that algorithm anyway ..

Comment: See [Fisher–Yates shuffle - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator about the method of generating random numbers in a given range

Comment: @Delfin Yes, 56 + 1. `rand() % N` generates a number from 0 to `N-1`. After adding 1, you get a number from 1 to N. So if you want numbers from 1 to 56, the code is `rand() % 56 + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your uniqueness test by iterating the current set with a loop where for all all *preceding* values you test for uniqueness from the current value:

```
            // Generate a unique random number
            bool unique = false ;
            while( !unique )
            {
                x[j] = rand() % RANGE + 1;  // Random 1 to 56

                // Test uniqueness from all preceding values in 
                // the set (x[0] is always unique)
                unique = true ;
                for( int k = 1; unique && k < j; k++ )
                {
                    unique = x[k] != x[j] ;
                }
            }
```

Note that if the set length is large, then the *scan all preceding values* approach may be sub-optimal, but in this case seems reasonable and is simple.

Since you (kind of) asked, the code can be further improved by (for example - code incorporating these follows):

- Eliminate magic numbers
- Initialisation of the first member of an array, initialises all remaining members to zero.
- Initialise on instantiation (rather then define and separately assign).
- Instantiate at narrowest possible scope - not all at the top of the function
- Don't open a file for access types you are not using ("w" not "w+")
- Error check I/O functions
- Do not use stdint types unnecessarily - arithmetic operations frequently result in implicit casts to `int`. Use `int` unless there is good reason not to to avoid surprises.  Good reasons to use stdint include conformance to some file format or comms protocol, or to match a register width in a device driver.  Not here.
- Test and fix bugs (`rand() % 57 + 1`) for example.
- Avoid repetition - use a loop (the uniqueness test in this case).
- Only say something useful in comments.  If the code is self documenting, keep quiet.  If it is not obvious, explain - do not simply repeat what anyone can see from the code (e.g. "Generating Random Number")
- Do not write comments in *present continuous* tense (no 'ing verbs).  OK, not really an improvement, just something I find annoying ;-).  The source code describes something the program *will* do, not what it *is* doing.
- Do not write extraneous space after last value on each line.
- Remove unnecessary code - e.g. the loop at the end zeroing `x[]`
- If you promise to return a value, return a value.

```
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

#define SET_LENGTH 6    // Number of values in each set
#define SET_COUNT 100   // Number of sets
#define RANGE 56        // Range of each value 1 to RANGE

int main() 
{ 
    // Initialing Random Generation C Library
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    int x[SET_LENGTH] = {0};

    // Open file
    FILE* fp = fopen( "combinations.txt", "w" ) ; 
    if( fp != NULL )
    {
        // For each random number set...
        for( int i = 0; !ferror( fp ) && i < SET_COUNT; i++ )
        {
            // For each number in the set...
            for( int j = 0; j < SET_LENGTH; j++) 
            {
                // Generate a unique random number
                bool unique = false ;
                while( !unique )
                {
                    x[j] = rand() % RANGE + 1;  // Random 1 to 56

                    // Test uniqueness from all preceding values in 
                    // the set (x[0] is always unique)
                    unique = true ;
                    for( int k = 1; unique && k < j; k++ )
                    {
                        unique = x[k] != x[j] ;
                    }
                }

                // Write value to file. 
                // Space separated values with newline end.
                fprintf(fp, "%d%c",x[j], 
                        j < SET_LENGTH - 1? ' ' : '\n' ) ;
            } 
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Not "improved" here is the issue of "random bias" that occurs when for `rand() % n`, `n` is not a factor of `RAND_MAX+1`.  If the randomness is critical, you may want to consider that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using an array of used values.

For example add:

```
uint8_t used[56] = {0};
```

between the first and second `for` loops

Then select your value this way:

```
do
{
  x[j] = rand() % 56 + 1;  // Generating Random Number
} while (used[x[j]-1] != 0);
used[x[j]-1] == 1;
```

When a value is used, we put a 1 at that location in the array.
When looking for a value, we loop until we find an empty slot.

To use the shuffle array instead, you would do this.

Create an array with all values before the first `for`-loop:

```
uint8_t shuffle[56] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, /* ... */ 54, 55, 56 };
```

Then choose your values this way:

```
uint8_t pos = rand() % (56-j);  // Generating Random Number Location
x[j] = shuffle[pos];  // Selecting Random Number
shuffle[pos] = shuffle[55];
shuffle[55] = x[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
#define NUM_RANDOM_NUMBERS 56

// Include all possible numbers.
int range[NUM_RANDOM_NUMBERS];

// Record current size of the array (this could be dynamic if we don't know the starting size...
int curSize = NUM_RANDOM_NUMBERS;

int getRandom()
{
    // If we are called with curSize at 0 or less, this is an error condition.  We have no numbers to return.
    assert(curSize > 0);

    // Get a number from our table and place it into a return Value.
    int index = random() % curSize;
    int retValue = range[index];

    // Move all the values above the index over the swapped out value.
    // memmove would probably be more efficient.
    for(int i = index; i < curSize - 1; i++) 
        range[i] = range[i+1];

    // Reduce the size of our pool of numbers.
    curSize--;

    // Return the value;
    return retValue;
}

int main()
{
    // Load the range pool with all the possible numbers.
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_RANDOM_NUMBERS; i++)
    {
        range[i] = i+1;    
    }

    // Now retreive them in random order.
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_RANDOM_NUMBERS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", getRandom());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I am calling random a minimum numbers of times with this.  The longest part of this runtime is probably the moving of the memory in the range pool, but it will run a deterministic amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function below to generate a combination of k integer from a set of N integers.
It returns k values from 0 to N-1 inside the variable arr which is an array.

```
void random_combination(int *arr, int N, int k){
    // function returning shuffled indexes 
    // arr: array to receive shuffled indexes
    // N: size of the array
    // k: number of index to return. Must be lower or equal to N
    int used[N];            // storage of already picked indexes
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) used[i]=0;
    int cnt;                // counter for unused indexes
    int r;                  // holds the random number
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++){
        r = rand() % (N-i);     // generate random number modulo the remaining number of unused indexes
        cnt = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){    // going through each used/unused indexes
            if (used[j]==0){
                if (cnt==r){
                    used[j] = 1;
                    arr[i] = j;
                    //printf("r: %d j: %d\n", r, j); // uncomment me to see what I do.
                    break;
                }
                cnt++;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For your example here use it as follow

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// copy paste the above function here

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    srand(time(0));
    int NN = 56;
    int k = 6;
    int arr[NN];
    random_combination(arr, NN, k);
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++){
        printf(" %d", arr[i]+1);
        // do whatever is needed with arr[i]+1 here
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```